# Issue with contact form in a flash template web

Tags: php, xml, flash

Hi guys i hope hoy can heló me with this. 
Ok so lets go.
I'm working on a flash template from templare monster. Is a simple problem But i cant solve it :(
The thing is that when i open the .HTML file of the templare (which call for the .swf file) everything works fine. Even the contact form. But when i open the .fla file And wihtout make changes i export the .swf ( or publish it) everything works cine except the contact form. And with that i mean i cant write in it. Even i cant write numbers. I contra know why.

The files of configuration  And structure(.XML) aré loares properly And the contact (php & asp) files too. 
So i really dont. Understand why i cant write properly.

What do you think ??? Pliz help
Pd: this is the link uploaded for me of the template.
Thanks
http://www.2shared.com/file/xbGOYnzC/TM20653ByWMForce.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to download your files through the link you provided but couldn't. The only thing I could download is the Free Download Manager :D

Rob

Comment: Hi mate, I checked your files. The problem is the fonts are not embedded, so the input fields use device fonts with the lowercase English chars only. Embed  all the chars you want to use with the proper font and it will be fine then. Rob

Comment: really? is just that?  nice!. But which one will be the "proper" font?

Comment: dont knwo how to do it too, cause if i go to the Text->font embedding
i just dont know what to do... can you help me with this?

Comment: Just go inside the contact form MovieClip and select the textfields, then on the Properties panel Select the font and style you want to use (if it is different to the one is already set) and then press the [Embed...] button. In the 'Font Embedding' panel select the Character ranges you want to use. Ranges contain different sets of characters like allcaps latin chars (ABCD...) or Numbers. There you'll see what you need to do.

Comment: it seems this works!!! but the thing that i did was.
open the .fla then text->font embedding-> and add every font from the folder font.
export the movie and everything works.! THANKYOU VERY MUCH.
pd: i couldnt do what you say i couldnt find: the textfields of the contact form and the properties panel :(.

Comment: Yeah, I am happy you could do it eventually.